# App rejected NSUrlConnection IPv6 network issue iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, nsurlconnection, ipv6

iTunes App rejected.

Reason :

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone
>   running iOS 9.3.4 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, the app content failed to load.

We tested it in NAT64 network (setup from mac) and it's working fine , but Apple review team have an issue with IPv6 network.

We have used NSURLConnection for calling web service , but getting nil response.

`NSURLConnection:connectionDidFinishLoading:` is called but getting nil NSData response in IPv6 network , it’s working fine in IPv4 network

json parsing code

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions | NSJSONReadingAllowFragments | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

getting parsing error becauseof nil receivedData : The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

it's all working fine in IPv4 network , also in IPv6 connectionDidFinishLoading: called but why getting nil response ?

Answer (score 3):

Change your app NSURLSession. Use this delegate method to get the response

service url = "you parse your url here";

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:serviceurl];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [dataTask resume];
```

In this delegate method you just copy and paste your `connectionDidFinishLoading` , `connectionDidReceiveResponse`, `connectionDidReceiveData`, `connectionDidFailWithError` should be in else part of (NSURLSession *)session task:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
     completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler
    {
        NSLog(@"### handler 1");
        [self.responseData setLength:0];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
        didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {


    }
    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
    didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        if(error == nil)
        {

            NSLog(@"Download is Succesfull");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error %@",[error userInfo]);

        }
    }
```

I think this is helpful to you.